# Broadcasting event to a private channel fails in authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have this event

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Events;
  
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use App\Models\User;
  
class PrivateMessage implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
  
    public $data = ['privatedata'];
    
    public $user;

  
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
     $this->user = $user;
    }
  
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user-' . $this->user->id);
    }
  
    /**
     * The event's broadcast name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'PrivateUserEvent';
    }
    /**
     * The event's broadcast name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['title'=>'Private Channel Code Is--'.rand()];
    }
}
```

that i am using to send a message to a private channel. On the client side, i have this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var id_of_logged_in_user = "<?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>";
        var i = 0;
        window.Echo.private('user-' + id_of_logged_in_user)
         .listen('.PrivateUserEvent', (data) => {
             alert();
            i++;
            $("#notification").append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+i+'.'+data.title+'</div>');
        });
    </script>
```

but my laravel echo server is giving me this

```
Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404
```

is there a problem in how i am setting up my event to send message to the private channel?

My channels code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

This is my `laravel-echo-server.json`

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check this? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#defining-authorization-routes

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it like this.

Inside `channels.php`

instead of using middleware `auth` i used `web`

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{id}', function($user, $id) {
return true;
});
```

In the client

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var id_of_logged_in_user = "<?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>";
     //alert(id_of_logged_in_user);
        var i = 0;
        window.Echo.private('user.' + id_of_logged_in_user)
         .listen('.PrivateUserEvent', (data) => {
            i++;
            $("#notification").append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+i+'.'+data.title+'</div>');
        });
    </script>
```

and in the event

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('user.' . $this->user->id);
}
```

the auth url should be `"authHost": "http://localhost:8000",`